# Chrome Extension, Closing tab

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

So Basically, I have code which opens a url. When it opens the url, it runs a javascript code.
After it has run this I want the tab to close and then continue on, how do I go about this ?

Thanks,

Comment: We need more specifics to be able to give you a good answer. Is the code you want to close after running a content script? Is there a reason you are not using [`chrome.tabs.remove()`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-remove)?

Comment: I am just using scripts via the manifest.json. At the moment, It is setup: When I press the chrome extension, it loads a url, runs a code and thats it. After it runs the code, I need it to close, but when i try chrome.tabs.remove() It just doesn't open the url. In background.js

Comment: From that, this sounds like a debugging question. So...

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a [mcve] that duplicates the problem. For Chrome extensions or Firefox WebExtensions this almost always means including your *manifest.json* and some of the background, content, and/or popup scripts/HTML. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *in the question itself*. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Comment: The reason that a [mcve] is required is that *we want to help*. It is **much** easier to help if we don't have to recreate any of the code needed to duplicate the problem. This is code that you already have. So, please help us to help you and provide a *complete* [mcve] that duplicates the problem. Without a [mcve], the amount of effort required to even begin to help you is **much** higher, which *significantly* reduces the number of people willing/able to help you. Even if we put out the extra effort, we have to **guess** at significant portions of what your problem might be.